# What crypto algorithms does Android support?

Tags: android, cryptography

I have been googling for hours and cannot find any solid answers but lots of hearsay.

Does anyone know where the documentation is that defines which encryption/signature/hash algorithms the Android OS supports.

I have heard from forums that not all phones support the same algorithms so I am looking for what common algorithms every Android phone supports.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this to list all security providers:

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider provider : providers) {
    Log.i("CRYPTO","provider: "+provider.getName());
    Set<Provider.Service> services = provider.getServices();
    for (Provider.Service service : services) {
        Log.i("CRYPTO","  algorithm: "+service.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is a list for my Nexus S (OS 2.3.4):

```
provider: AndroidOpenSSL
 algorithm: SHA-384
 algorithm: SHA-1
 algorithm: SSLv3
 algorithm: MD5
 algorithm: SSL
 algorithm: SHA-256
 algorithm: TLS
 algorithm: SHA-512
 algorithm: TLSv1
 algorithm: Default
provider: DRLCertFactory
 algorithm: X509
provider: BC
 algorithm: PKCS12
 algorithm: DESEDE
 algorithm: DH
 algorithm: RC4
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: DESEDE
 algorithm: Collection
 algorithm: SHA-1
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: AES
 algorithm: HMACSHA256
 algorithm: OAEP
 algorithm: HMACSHA256
 algorithm: HMACSHA384
 algorithm: DSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: DES
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
 algorithm: SHA1withDSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
 algorithm: BouncyCastle
 algorithm: PKIX
 algorithm: PKCS12PBE
 algorithm: DSA
 algorithm: RSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
 algorithm: DESEDE
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
 algorithm: DH
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
 algorithm: HMACSHA384
 algorithm: AESWRAP
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
 algorithm: DES
 algorithm: HMACSHA512
 algorithm: HMACSHA1
 algorithm: DH
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PKIX
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
 algorithm: SHA-256
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
 algorithm: HMACSHA512
 algorithm: SHA384WithRSAEncryption
 algorithm: DES
 algorithm: BLOWFISH
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: DSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
 algorithm: BLOWFISH
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
 algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
 algorithm: HMACSHA1
 algorithm: AES
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
 algorithm: DH
 algorithm: BKS
 algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
 algorithm: DES
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
 algorithm: DSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
 algorithm: SHA512WithRSAEncryption
 algorithm: HMACMD5
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
 algorithm: ARC4
 algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
 algorithm: AES
 algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
 algorithm: MD5
 algorithm: RSA
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
 algorithm: SHA-384
 algorithm: RSA
 algorithm: DESEDE
 algorithm: SHA-512
 algorithm: X.509
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: MD5WithRSAEncryption
 algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 algorithm: BLOWFISH
 algorithm: DH
 algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption
 algorithm: HMACMD5
 algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
provider: Crypto
 algorithm: SHA1withDSA
 algorithm: SHA-1
 algorithm: DSA
 algorithm: SHA1PRNG
provider: HarmonyJSSE
 algorithm: X509
 algorithm: SSLv3
 algorithm: TLS
 algorithm: TLSv1
 algorithm: X509
 algorithm: SSL
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I realize that will list each available one. The problem is that I have heard that different phones and different OS versions support different algorithms. So this will only really tell me what one specific phone supports, which is not very useful. I am more looking for Google documentation specifying which algorithms must always be supported.

Comment: I'm posting the list for my Nexus S here, so you can compare with yours. Maybe some other people will add theirs.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that. I am thinking maybe if there is no official documentation my best best is to look at the OS source code factories to see which algorithms they support. I could try going back a few OS revs to see if anything has changed. I am generally scared of looking things up like that because its really no guarantee that it won't change in the future if they didn't commit to it in writing.

Comment: I googled around for such info but couldn't find anything. AFAIK the only source code available is from Google, so you don't have much to compare it to.

Comment: If you want to make sure that a particular algorithm is available on all devices, then you have to include it with your app as an external library. Take a look at Bouncy Castle: http://bouncycastle.org/documentation.html

Comment: Err, even better - Spongy Castle, specifically for Android: https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle#readme

Comment: The Bouncy Castle is actually included (in crippled form) with Android. The "BC" provider above in my post is Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Yeah I heard it came with Bouncy Castle but that different phones came with different versions so its not terribly safe to use. I think you are right. If I just embed the Spongy Castle into my App than I know for a fact that every phone it runs on will support those algorithms. I think this is the real answer here.

Answer (score 8):

The official cipher list can be found here. alot are supported from SDK 1 but even more from SDK 10: https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Comment: This answer should get accepted. It is the only one which really answers the question intead of providing lists of algorithms supported by specific devices.

Answer (score 7):

The same list updated with android 4.2.2

```
I/CRYPTO  (32293): provider: AndroidOpenSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: MD5
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-512
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-256
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLSv1.1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLSv1.2
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SSLv3
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLSv1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLS
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: Default
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-384
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO  (32293): provider: DRLCertFactory
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: X509
I/CRYPTO  (32293): provider: BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-256
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: ECDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACMD5
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-384
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: BouncyCastle
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: AESWRAP
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: MD5
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: BKS
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: X.509
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: ARC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PKCS12
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: ARC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-512
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: Collection
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: HMACMD5
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: ECDH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: OAEP
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293): provider: Crypto
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA-1
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO  (32293): provider: HarmonyJSSE
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SSLv3
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: X509
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: X509
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLS
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: SSL
I/CRYPTO  (32293):   algorithm: TLSv1
```

Answer (score 4):

The list for ICS 4.0.3:

```
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701): provider: AndroidOpenSSL
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-512
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SSL
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: TLSv1
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-256
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: MD5
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SSLv3
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: TLS
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-384
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-1
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: Default
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701): provider: DRLCertFactory
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: X509
02-10 10:50:04.192: I/CRYPTO(1701): provider: BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: AES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: AESWRAP
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: EC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-256
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACMD5
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA384WithRSAEncryption
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: ECDH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: BouncyCastle
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: BKS
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: MD5WithRSAEncryption
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: MD5
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: ARC4
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: RSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DESEDE
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: RSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: AES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: X.509
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PKCS12
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA512WithRSAEncryption
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PKIX
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: AES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-512
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: RSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: OAEP
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DESEDE
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: ECDSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DSA
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DESEDE
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: HMACMD5
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-384
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: EC
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DH
02-10 10:50:04.200: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PKIX
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DSA
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: ARC4
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DESEDE
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DES
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: Collection
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701): provider: Crypto
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: DSA
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA-1
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701): provider: HarmonyJSSE
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: TLSv1
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SSLv3
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: TLS
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: X509
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: SSL
02-10 10:50:04.208: I/CRYPTO(1701):   algorithm: X509
```

Answer (score 3):

A list for Android 4.4.2 on Nexus 5

```
provider: AndroidOpenSSL
algorithm:  SSL
algorithm:  SSLv3
algorithm:  TLS
algorithm:  TLSv1
algorithm:  TLSv1.1
algorithm:  TLSv1.2
algorithm:  Default
algorithm:  SHA-1
algorithm:  SHA-256
algorithm:  SHA-384
algorithm:  SHA-512
algorithm:  MD5
algorithm:  RSA
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  EC
algorithm:  RSA
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  EC
algorithm:  ECDH
algorithm:  MD5WithRSA
algorithm:  SHA1WithRSA
algorithm:  SHA256WithRSA
algorithm:  SHA384WithRSA
algorithm:  SHA512WithRSA
algorithm:  SHA1withDSA
algorithm:  NONEwithRSA
algorithm:  ECDSA
algorithm:  SHA256withECDSA
algorithm:  SHA384withECDSA
algorithm:  SHA512withECDSA
algorithm:  SHA1PRNG
algorithm:  RSA/ECB/NoPadding
algorithm:  RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
algorithm:  AES/ECB/NoPadding
algorithm:  AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  AES/CBC/NoPadding
algorithm:  AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  AES/CFB/NoPadding
algorithm:  AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  AES/CTR/NoPadding
algorithm:  AES/CTR/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  AES/OFB/NoPadding
algorithm:  AES/OFB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
algorithm:  DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  DESEDE/CFB/NoPadding
algorithm:  DESEDE/CFB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  DESEDE/ECB/NoPadding
algorithm:  DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  DESEDE/OFB/NoPadding
algorithm:  DESEDE/OFB/PKCS5Padding
algorithm:  ARC4
algorithm:  HmacMD5
algorithm:  HmacSHA1
algorithm:  HmacSHA256
algorithm:  HmacSHA384
algorithm:  HmacSHA512
algorithm:  X509
provider: DRLCertFactory
algorithm:  X509
provider: BC
algorithm:  MD5
algorithm:  HMACMD5
algorithm:  HMACMD5
algorithm:  SHA-1
algorithm:  HMACSHA1
algorithm:  HMACSHA1
algorithm:  PBEWITHHMACSHA
algorithm:  PBEWITHHMACSHA1
algorithm:  PBEWITHHMACSHA1
algorithm:  PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
algorithm:  PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
algorithm:  SHA-256
algorithm:  HMACSHA256
algorithm:  HMACSHA256
algorithm:  SHA-384
algorithm:  HMACSHA384
algorithm:  HMACSHA384
algorithm:  SHA-512
algorithm:  HMACSHA512
algorithm:  HMACSHA512
algorithm:  PKCS12PBE
algorithm:  AES
algorithm:  AES
algorithm:  AESWRAP
algorithm:  AES
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
algorithm:  ARC4
algorithm:  ARC4
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
algorithm:  BLOWFISH
algorithm:  BLOWFISH
algorithm:  BLOWFISH
algorithm:  DES
algorithm:  DES
algorithm:  DES
algorithm:  DES
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
algorithm:  DESEDE
algorithm:  DESEDEWRAP
algorithm:  DESEDE
algorithm:  DESEDE
algorithm:  DESEDE
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
algorithm:  PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
algorithm:  X.509
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  DSA
algorithm:  SHA1withDSA
algorithm:  NONEWITHDSA
algorithm:  DH
algorithm:  DH
algorithm:  DH
algorithm:  DH
algorithm:  DH
algorithm:  ECDH
algorithm:  EC
algorithm:  EC
algorithm:  ECDSA
algorithm:  NONEwithECDSA
algorithm:  SHA256WITHECDSA
algorithm:  SHA384WITHECDSA
algorithm:  SHA512WITHECDSA
algorithm:  OAEP
algorithm:  RSA
algorithm:  RSA
algorithm:  RSA
algorithm:  MD5WITHRSA
algorithm:  SHA1WITHRSA
algorithm:  SHA256WITHRSA
algorithm:  SHA384WITHRSA
algorithm:  SHA512WITHRSA
algorithm:  BKS
algorithm:  BouncyCastle
algorithm:  PKCS12
algorithm:  PKIX
algorithm:  PKIX
algorithm:  Collection
provider: Crypto
algorithm:  SHA-1
algorithm:  SHA1PRNG
algorithm:  SHA1withDSA
algorithm:  DSA
provider: HarmonyJSSE
algorithm:  SSL
algorithm:  SSLv3
algorithm:  TLS
algorithm:  TLSv1
algorithm:  PKIX
algorithm:  PKIX
algorithm:  AndroidCAStore
provider: AndroidKeyStore
algorithm:  AndroidKeyStore
algorithm:  RSA
```

Answer (score 3):

A list for Android 5.0 on Nexus 5

```
 provider: AndroidOpenSSL
   algorithm: SSL
   algorithm: SSLv3
   algorithm: TLS
   algorithm: TLSv1
   algorithm: TLSv1.1
   algorithm: TLSv1.2
   algorithm: Default
   algorithm: SHA-1
   algorithm: SHA-224
   algorithm: SHA-256
   algorithm: SHA-384
   algorithm: SHA-512
   algorithm: MD5
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: ECDH
   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
   algorithm: ECDSA
   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: AES/CFB/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/OFB/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: DESEDE/CFB/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/OFB/NoPadding
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: HmacMD5
   algorithm: HmacSHA1
   algorithm: HmacSHA224
   algorithm: HmacSHA256
   algorithm: HmacSHA384
   algorithm: HmacSHA512
   algorithm: X509
 provider: BC
   algorithm: MD5
   algorithm: HMACMD5
   algorithm: HMACMD5
   algorithm: SHA-1
   algorithm: HMACSHA1
   algorithm: HMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
   algorithm: SHA-224
   algorithm: HMACSHA224
   algorithm: HMACSHA224
   algorithm: SHA-256
   algorithm: HMACSHA256
   algorithm: HMACSHA256
   algorithm: SHA-384
   algorithm: HMACSHA384
   algorithm: HMACSHA384
   algorithm: SHA-512
   algorithm: HMACSHA512
   algorithm: HMACSHA512
   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: GCM
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: AESWRAP
   algorithm: GCM
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
   algorithm: X.509
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: ECDH
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: ECDSA
   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
   algorithm: OAEP
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
   algorithm: BKS
   algorithm: BouncyCastle
   algorithm: PKCS12
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: Collection
 provider: Crypto
   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
 provider: HarmonyJSSE
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
 provider: AndroidKeyStore
   algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
   algorithm: RSA
```

Answer (score 2):

A list for `6.0.0` (M) Emulator

```
provider: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround
  algorithm: HmacSHA1
  algorithm: HmacSHA224
  algorithm: HmacSHA256
  algorithm: HmacSHA384
  algorithm: HmacSHA512
  algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
  algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding
  algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
  algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
  algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
  algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-224AndMGF1Padding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding
  algorithm: NONEwithRSA
  algorithm: MD5withRSA
  algorithm: SHA1withRSA
  algorithm: SHA224withRSA
  algorithm: SHA256withRSA
  algorithm: SHA384withRSA
  algorithm: SHA512withRSA
  algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
  algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
  algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
  algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
  algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
  algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
  algorithm: ECDSA
  algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
provider: AndroidOpenSSL
  algorithm: SSL
  algorithm: SSLv3
  algorithm: TLS
  algorithm: TLSv1
  algorithm: TLSv1.1
  algorithm: TLSv1.2
  algorithm: Default
  algorithm: SHA-1
  algorithm: SHA-224
  algorithm: SHA-256
  algorithm: SHA-384
  algorithm: SHA-512
  algorithm: MD5
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: ECDH
  algorithm: MD5WithRSA
  algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
  algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
  algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
  algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
  algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
  algorithm: NONEwithRSA
  algorithm: ECDSA
  algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
  algorithm: SHA1PRNG
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
  algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
  algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
  algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
  algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
  algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
  algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
  algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
  algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
  algorithm: ARC4
  algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
  algorithm: HmacMD5
  algorithm: HmacSHA1
  algorithm: HmacSHA224
  algorithm: HmacSHA256
  algorithm: HmacSHA384
  algorithm: HmacSHA512
  algorithm: X509
provider: BC
  algorithm: MD5
  algorithm: HMACMD5
  algorithm: HMACMD5
  algorithm: SHA-1
  algorithm: HMACSHA1
  algorithm: HMACSHA1
  algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
  algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
  algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
  algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
  algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
  algorithm: SHA-224
  algorithm: HMACSHA224
  algorithm: HMACSHA224
  algorithm: SHA-256
  algorithm: HMACSHA256
  algorithm: HMACSHA256
  algorithm: SHA-384
  algorithm: HMACSHA384
  algorithm: HMACSHA384
  algorithm: SHA-512
  algorithm: HMACSHA512
  algorithm: HMACSHA512
  algorithm: PKCS12PBE
  algorithm: AES
  algorithm: GCM
  algorithm: AES
  algorithm: AESWRAP
  algorithm: AES/GCM/NOPADDING
  algorithm: AES
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
  algorithm: ARC4
  algorithm: ARC4
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
  algorithm: BLOWFISH
  algorithm: BLOWFISH
  algorithm: BLOWFISH
  algorithm: DES
  algorithm: DES
  algorithm: DES
  algorithm: DES
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
  algorithm: DESEDE
  algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
  algorithm: DESEDE
  algorithm: DESEDE
  algorithm: DESEDE
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
  algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
  algorithm: X.509
  algorithm: DSA
  algorithm: DSA
  algorithm: DSA
  algorithm: DSA
  algorithm: SHA1withDSA
  algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
  algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
  algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
  algorithm: DH
  algorithm: DH
  algorithm: DH
  algorithm: DH
  algorithm: DH
  algorithm: ECDH
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: ECDSA
  algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
  algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
  algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
  algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
  algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
  algorithm: OAEP
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
  algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
  algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
  algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
  algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
  algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
  algorithm: BKS
  algorithm: BouncyCastle
  algorithm: PKCS12
  algorithm: PKIX
  algorithm: PKIX
  algorithm: Collection
provider: Crypto
  algorithm: SHA1PRNG
provider: HarmonyJSSE
  algorithm: PKIX
  algorithm: PKIX
  algorithm: AndroidCAStore
provider: AndroidKeyStore
  algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: EC
  algorithm: RSA
  algorithm: AES
  algorithm: HmacSHA1
  algorithm: HmacSHA224
  algorithm: HmacSHA256
  algorithm: HmacSHA384
  algorithm: HmacSHA512
  algorithm: AES
  algorithm: HmacSHA1
  algorithm: HmacSHA224
  algorithm: HmacSHA256
  algorithm: HmacSHA384
  algorithm: HmacSHA512
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.3.1, API 18

```
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO: provider: AndroidOpenSSL
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SSL
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SSLv3
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLS
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLSv1
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLSv1.1
04-03 19:29:58.544     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLSv1.2
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: Default
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-256
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-384
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-512
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: MD5
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: EC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: EC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ECDH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: MD5WithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1withDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: NONEwithRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1PRNG
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CFB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/CTR/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/OFB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES/OFB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/CFB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/CFB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/OFB/NoPadding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE/OFB/PKCS5Padding
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ARC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HmacMD5
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HmacSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HmacSHA256
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HmacSHA384
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HmacSHA512
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: X509
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO: provider: DRLCertFactory
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: X509
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO: provider: BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: MD5
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACMD5
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACMD5
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-256
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA256
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA256
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-384
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA384
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA384
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-512
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA512
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: HMACSHA512
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AESWRAP
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ARC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ARC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: BLOWFISH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: BLOWFISH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: BLOWFISH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DESEDE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: X.509
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1withDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ECDH
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: EC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: EC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: ECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: OAEP
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: BKS
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: BouncyCastle
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKCS12
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKCS12PBE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKIX
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKIX
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: Collection
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO: provider: Crypto
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA-1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1PRNG
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SHA1withDSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: DSA
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO: provider: HarmonyJSSE
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SSL
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: SSLv3
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLS
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: TLSv1
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKIX
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: PKIX
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AndroidCAStore
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO: provider: AndroidKeyStore
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
04-03 19:29:58.554     CRYPTO:       algorithm: RSA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update for Android 5.1.1 (Nexus 5 Stock).

```
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949): provider: AndroidOpenSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SSLv3
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: TLS
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: TLSv1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: TLSv1.1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: TLSv1.2
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: Default
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-224
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-256
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-384
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-512
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: MD5
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: EC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: EC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ECDH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/CFB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES/OFB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/CFB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE/OFB/NoPadding
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ARC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacMD5
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacSHA224
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacSHA256
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacSHA384
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HmacSHA512
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: X509
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949): provider: BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: MD5
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACMD5
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACMD5
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-224
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA224
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA224
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-256
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA256
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-384
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA384
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA-512
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: HMACSHA512
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: GCM
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AESWRAP
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: GCM
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ARC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ARC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: BLOWFISH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DESEDE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: X.509
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: DH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ECDH
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: EC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: EC
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: ECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: OAEP
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: BKS
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: BouncyCastle
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKCS12
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKIX
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKIX
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: Collection
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949): provider: Crypto
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949): provider: HarmonyJSSE
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKIX
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: PKIX
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949): provider: AndroidKeyStore
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
    I/CRYPTO  ( 1949):   algorithm: RSA
```

Answer (score 1):

A list for `7.0.0` (N) Emulator

```
 provider: AndroidNSSP
   algorithm: PKIX
 provider: AndroidOpenSSL
   algorithm: SSL
   algorithm: SSLv3
   algorithm: TLS
   algorithm: TLSv1
   algorithm: TLSv1.1
   algorithm: TLSv1.2
   algorithm: Default
   algorithm: SHA-1
   algorithm: SHA-224
   algorithm: SHA-256
   algorithm: SHA-384
   algorithm: SHA-512
   algorithm: MD5
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: ECDH
   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
   algorithm: HmacMD5
   algorithm: HmacSHA1
   algorithm: HmacSHA224
   algorithm: HmacSHA256
   algorithm: HmacSHA384
   algorithm: HmacSHA512
   algorithm: X509
 provider: CertPathProvider
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: PKIX
 provider: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround
   algorithm: HmacSHA1
   algorithm: HmacSHA224
   algorithm: HmacSHA256
   algorithm: HmacSHA384
   algorithm: HmacSHA512
   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-224AndMGF1Padding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding
   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding
   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
   algorithm: MD5withRSA
   algorithm: SHA1withRSA
   algorithm: SHA224withRSA
   algorithm: SHA256withRSA
   algorithm: SHA384withRSA
   algorithm: SHA512withRSA
   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
 provider: BC
   algorithm: MD5
   algorithm: HMACMD5
   algorithm: HMACMD5
   algorithm: SHA-1
   algorithm: HMACSHA1
   algorithm: HMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
   algorithm: SHA-224
   algorithm: HMACSHA224
   algorithm: HMACSHA224
   algorithm: SHA-256
   algorithm: HMACSHA256
   algorithm: HMACSHA256
   algorithm: SHA-384
   algorithm: HMACSHA384
   algorithm: HMACSHA384
   algorithm: SHA-512
   algorithm: HMACSHA512
   algorithm: HMACSHA512
   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: GCM
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: AESWRAP
   algorithm: AES/GCM/NOPADDING
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: ARC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: BLOWFISH
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: DES
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: DESEDE
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
   algorithm: X.509
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: DSA
   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: DH
   algorithm: ECDH
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
   algorithm: OAEP
   algorithm: PSS
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
   algorithm: BKS
   algorithm: BouncyCastle
   algorithm: PKCS12
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: Collection
 provider: HarmonyJSSE
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: PKIX
   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
 provider: AndroidKeyStore
   algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: EC
   algorithm: RSA
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: HmacSHA1
   algorithm: HmacSHA224
   algorithm: HmacSHA256
   algorithm: HmacSHA384
   algorithm: HmacSHA512
   algorithm: AES
   algorithm: HmacSHA1
   algorithm: HmacSHA224
   algorithm: HmacSHA256
   algorithm: HmacSHA384
   algorithm: HmacSHA512
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android 7.1.1**

```
 I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidNSSP
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidOpenSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SSLv3
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1.1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1.2
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: Default
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ECDH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacMD5
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: X509
 I/CRYPTO: provider: CertPathProvider
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-224AndMGF1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
 I/CRYPTO: provider: BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACMD5
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACMD5
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: GCM
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AESWRAP
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NOPADDING
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
0 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BLOWFISH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BLOWFISH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BLOWFISH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: X.509
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ECDH
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: OAEP
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PSS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BKS
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BouncyCastle
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKCS12
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: Collection
 I/CRYPTO: provider: HarmonyJSSE
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
 I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidKeyStore
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
 E/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android 8.0.0**

```
I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidNSSP
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidOpenSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1.1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: TLSv1.2
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: Default
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ECDH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1PRNG
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-224AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_128/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_128/ECB/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_128/CBC/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_128/CBC/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_256/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_256/ECB/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_256/CBC/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_256/CBC/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_128/GCM/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES_256/GCM/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacMD5
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: X509
I/CRYPTO: provider: CertPathProvider
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/CTR/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/NoPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-224AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withRSA/PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512withECDSA
I/CRYPTO: provider: BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACMD5
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACMD5
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA-512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HMACSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8BIT
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKCS12PBE
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: GCM
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AESWRAP
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES/GCM/NOPADDING
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND192BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ARC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BLOWFISH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BLOWFISH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDEWRAP
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DESEDE
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PBEWITHSHAANDTWOFISH-CBC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: X.509
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEWITHDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: DH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: ECDH
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1withECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: NONEwithECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WITHECDSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: OAEP
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PSS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: MD5WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA224WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA384WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: SHA512WITHRSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BKS
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: BouncyCastle
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKCS12
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: Collection
I/CRYPTO: provider: HarmonyJSSE
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: PKIX
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AndroidCAStore
I/CRYPTO: provider: AndroidKeyStore
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AndroidKeyStore
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: EC
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: RSA
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: AES
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA1
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA224
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA256
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA384
I/CRYPTO:   algorithm: HmacSHA512
```