# Security Provider at Android App (SunEC)

Tags: java, android, security

Hi I am developing a android 4.2.2 with sdk version 8 to 17, where I need to use a Private Key,
so when I am going to generate this key, I use the following code:

```
Provider p = Security.getProvider("SunEC");
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC",p);
```

however the p is null.

the same code works when I run at a java project, however not in the android project

Do I need to set a lib in the project? or any other thing?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an invalid security provider on Android.

See: [What crypto algorithms does Android support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560974/what-crypto-algroithms-does-android-support)

Comment: but if I would like to add it ?

Comment: @eduardo_hito You could if Oracle provides the source. You would have to implement the entire thing as it wouldn't come in the standard Android Open Source Project.

Comment: thank you, but still do I really need de src code?  because I have the .jar with the .class.....I have added the jar to the buildpath of the project, however it doesn't export it to the application in the smartphone

Comment: @eduardo_hito If you search around it looks like the Java code uses a native library (C-code) and I don't know where that code comes from. Also remember Android only supports Java 6 not Java 7 features.

Comment: @eduardo_hito At some point do accept answers on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had fix the problem,

As @Morrison Chang had point out, I was using a provider that is not supported on Android yet.

The sun provider was release this year at jdk 1.7, however the Android system it's still at 1.6.

I tried to use the Bouncy Castle provider, it works very well at no mobile system. But they have a version for mobile sytem that works pretty well

Spongy Castle.
http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/

Thank you all!